# Powershell - Get the first and last day of the previous month

Tags: powershell, datetime

For example , If I run the script on 11/1/2019 or any other day in November I want the date to be change like below.

```
$CURRENTDATE=GET-DATE -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
$FIRSTDAYOFMONTH=GET-DATE $CURRENTDATE -Day 1
$LASTDAYOFMONTH=GET-DATE $FIRSTDAYOFMONTH.AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1)

$FIRSTDAYOFMONTH
$LASTDAYOFMONTH
```

Output  :

```
Friday, November 1, 2019 12:00:00 AM
Saturday, November 30, 2019 11:59:59 PM
```

My desired output :

```
10/01/2019 00:00:00

10/31/2019 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the .net AddMonths() method on your current date object to go back (or forward in time).

And do the date formatting after you do the date math.

```
$CURRENTDATE=GET-DATE -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0
$MonthAgo = $CURRENTDATE.AddMonths(-1)
$FIRSTDAYOFMONTH=GET-DATE $MonthAgo -Day 1
$LASTDAYOFMONTH=GET-DATE $FIRSTDAYOFMONTH.AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1)

$FIRSTDAYOFMONTH.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
$LASTDAYOFMONTH.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Output:

```
10/01/2019 00:00:00
10/31/2019 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 9):

First Day of Previous Month

```
(Get-Date -Day 1).AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Last Day of Previous Month

```
(Get-Date -Day 1).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: Wonderful answer!

Answer (score 4):

here's a slightly different way to do the job ... [*grin*]

- get the 1st day of the current month
- use `.Date` to give midnite instead of `now` for the time
- back up one month to the the 1st day of the previous month
- back up on millisecond to get the last day of two moths ago
- dump the time part to get midnite again
- add a month to get the last day of *one* month ago

the code ...

```
$LastMonthFirstDay = (Get-Date -Day 1).Date.AddMonths(-1)
$LastMonthLastDay = (Get-Date -Day 1).Date.AddMonths(-1).AddMilliseconds(-1).Date.AddMonths(1)

$LastMonthFirstDay
$LastMonthLastDay
```

output for today [2019 November 22, Friday 3:56:23 PM] ...

```
2019 October 01, Tuesday 12:00:00 AM
2019 October 30, Wednesday 12:00:00 AM
```

if you want the last day to be just before the end of the day instead of at the start, remove the 2nd `.Date` in the `$LastMonthLastDay` code. that would give you this code & result for today [2019 November 22, Friday 3:56:23 PM] ...

```
(Get-Date -Day 1).Date.AddMonths(-1).AddMilliseconds(-1).AddMonths(1)
# 2019 October 30, Wednesday 11:59:59 PM
```